# how to update vuex state each time after submittnig the form?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Basically I'm using **Vue 3** and I'm trying to assign the error returned by the server for example if the email is already taken by another user. The first time it works fine, I can assign the message returned by the server to my `state.responseErrorMessage` property but when I try to re-send the from with a new email without refreshing the page, the ERROR_MESSAGE mutation doesn’t get updated!

### myComponent:

```vue
    <script>
        computed: {
        ...mapState(['responseSuccessMessage','responseErrorMessage']),
        },
        methods: {
          ...
          if( this.errors.firstname.errMsg === null && 
                  this.errors.lastname.errMsg === null && 
                  this.errors.email.errMsg === null && 
                  this.errors.password.errMsg === null && 
                  this.errors.passwordConfirm.errMsg === null &&
                  this.errors.terms.errMsg === null) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('creatAccount', {
                      firstName: this.firstname, 
                      lastName: this.lastname,
                      email: this.email,
                      password: this.password
                    })
                    setTimeout(() => { 
                      // first time submitting the form it display the error message but the second time it doesn't !   
                      console.log(this.responseErrorMessage)  
                    }, 2000)
                }
        }
     </script>
```

### Veux :

```vue
        export default createStore({
          state: {
            responseSuccessMessage: null,
            responseErrorMessage: null
          },
          mutations: {
              SUCCESS_MESSAGE(state, message) {
              state.responseSuccessMessage = message
            },
            ERROR_MESSAGE(state, message) {
              state.responseErrorMessage = message
              setInterval(() => {
                state.responseErrorMessage = null
              }, 3000)
            }
          },
          actions: { 
            async creatAccount({ context, commit, }, user) {
              try {
                let result = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signup', {
                  firstName: user.firstName,
                  lastName: user.lastName,
                  email: user.email,
                  password: user.password
                })
                if (result.status === 201) {
                  commit('SUCCESS_MESSAGE', result.data.message)
                  // state.responseSuccessMessage = result.data.message
                }
              } catch (err) {
                if (err.response.status === 409) {
                  context, commit, // Put this line to avoid eslint errors!
                    commit('ERROR_MESSAGE', err.response.data.message)
                } else {
                  console.log(err)
                }
              }
            }
          },
          modules: {}
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

please don't use asynchronous method(setInterval、setTimeout、promise、ajax...) in your mutation function, you can change your code, the code

```js
ERROR_MESSAGE(state, message) {
      state.responseErrorMessage = message
      setInterval(() => {
        state.responseErrorMessage = null
      }, 3000)
    }
```

you may want to reset the responeErrorMessage to null, but the way is incorrect， you can write like this:

mutation:

```js
ERROR_MESSAGE(state, message) {
      state.responseErrorMessage = message
    }
```

global watch:

```js
responseErrorMessage (New,Old){
  if(New){
    setTimeout(()=>{
     this.$store.commit('ERROR_MESSAGE',null)
    },3000)
  }
}
```

you can try it

Comment: Ok but does that mean i should declare the global variable function in my component right  ?

Comment: I don't how but after replacing setInterval with setTimeout the mutation works as intended ! Is this a bad implementation ?

Comment: no, I means the `watch` in vue ，responseErrorMessage looks like a  global state, and you shouldn't deal with it in a single vue component, instand you can declare the watch at vm like this: `vm = Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app')
vm.$watch('xxx', function (newValue, oldValue) {}`

Comment: no matter how the setInterval or setTimeout works in the mutation ,you shouldn't use the asynchronous method in it , instead of action , the action is design with asynchronous method special，and mutation's responsibility is only change the state

Comment: I applied your advice and it works too Thank 

Comment: It's my pleasure  :), and I'm a chinese , my english is not well ,I hope you can undestand my word